# Select dropdownlist option in IE11 with VBA

Tags: html, css, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

How do I select an option in HTML objects with VBA.

I tried many different syntax. These show runtime errors like 41,936.

I used `Dim optn as object, htmlselectelements, mhtml.htmlelements`

The code below gets the HTML code of the webpage:

```
docu = ie.document
```

**Type 1**

```
Set optn = docu.getElementById("categoryId")
optn.Focus
optn.selectedIndex = "2"
```

**Type 2**

```
Set optn = docu.getElementsByTagName("categoryId")
For Each op In optn
    If op.Value = "2" Then
        op.Click
Next
```

**Type 3**

```
docu.getElementsByName("categoryId")().Value = "2"
```

**Here is the webpage HTML code:**

[image]